# How can I print numbers from excel sheet1 that are there in excel sheet2 and that too repeated numbers must print only once?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_excel('excel_data.xlsx')     # This file has list of repeated numbers(1,1,2,3,5,5,9)
df2=pd.read_excel('excel_data2.xlsx')      # This file has list(1,2,3,4,5,6)
df = df2.merge(df1, how = 'inner' ,indicator=False)
print(df)
```

1- I want to print numbers from excel_data.xlsx that are there in excel_data2.xlsx and that too repeated numbers must print only once.(desired output- 1,2,3,4,5)

2- I'm getting repeated numbers like (1,1,2,3,5,5) in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line

```
    df = df2.merge(df1, how = 'inner' ,indicator=False)
    df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

You say your desired output is (1,2,3,4,5) however 4 doesn't appear in excel_data.xlsx. The current output minus duplicates seems to be what you're looking for!

Comment: Oh yes! 4 was surely a mistake. getting desired output now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries! Could you mark my solution as correct? Thanks